# Change the apache airflow webserver console context root path

Tags: airflow

Is there a way (preferably via configuration) to change the default url context path root of airflow webserver

i:e instead of deployment the server like

localhost:8080/admin/...

I would like the root path be like

localhost:8080/mywebserver/admin/...

I would like to avoid a reverse proxy in front of the airflow just to rewrite the root path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the [webserver] section in airflow.cfg and able to find the base_url configuration that helping to change the default URL context path.

Update the airflow.cfg and restart the webserver.

```
[webserver]
base_url = http://localhost:8080/mywebserver
```

[Airflow web ui with updated base_url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OMnt.png)

Comment: Thank you.Its working ,  I had seen that configuration but assumed it was being used only as a redirection.